# Will creating a 301 redirect from old domain to new domain affect Gmail?

Tags: domains, redirects, 301-redirect, gmail

I've rebranded a business so I want to redirect the existing site to a new domain name - presumably by setting up a **301 redirect**(?) - so anyone who types in **xxx1.com** (old domain) will be redirected to the new site at **xx2.com** (new domain).

The business email is currently with Gmail set up with the xx1.com domain and I want to keep the email coming to xx1.com (old domain), at least for the time being.

Will this redirect affect the Gmail setup at all? Will emails still come through to the @xx1.com email address after the domain redirect is set up?

(Note: I will be taking down the hosting of the old site too)

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't affect you receiving or sending email through Gmail, as that will be using the MX records and SPF TXT records of xx1.com.